# unable to post tweets to twitter using Outh

Tags: iphone, twitter

Iam Using Outh to add Twitter to my app and  I got the mail from twitter team as.

Thank you for writing in and we will respect the confidentiality of your images. Your application now has the ability to use xAuth, and our documentation is available here: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth .

Thanks,
Twitter API Policy

Now Iam getting login  to the twitter account with my app,but Iam unable to post the tweets.

Basically Iam using two different views one for login process and second one for posting the tweets.

My Questions is.

1.If I use only one view, tweets are posting.But as per my requirement I need to have post from another view.How I can achive?

Iam using this method to posting.

```
         [_engine sendUpdate:str];
```

please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you out:

[Oauth authorization callback](http://davidquail.com/2009/12/07/oauth-authorization-callback-on-the-iphone-with-webview/)

Answer (score 0):

AS like I answered for ur other post, U use the same **_engine** object in DetailViewController.
You can Achieve this as follows,
  Declare a object for the same SA_Twitter....Engine some class.
  U just assign this **_engine** object to the detailviewController while you loading that controller

Do the following in the necessary place of SettingsViewController

```
//This engine object should be declared @ .h of settings
    if ([SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:engine delegate:self]) {
                [self presentModalViewController:[SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:engine delegate:self] animated:YES];
            }
```

Declare a variable for SA_OAuthTwitterEngine in detailview

```
SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *_engine;

@property (nonatomic, retain) SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *_engine;
```

Finally while u moving from settigs to detailview,

```
    DetailView  *detailObj=[[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    detailObj._engine=self.engine;
    [self presentModalViewController:detailObj animated:YES];
    [detailObj release];
```

Comment: From Where I need to assign ?and how?please post me some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post what you have entered in text box, I may help you out here. 1. You must have included the twitter4j library in gradle file as follows:

```
compile group: 'org.twitter4j', name: 'twitter4j-core', version: '4.0.1'
```

2. Include following code snippet in your code:

```
public String sTweet;
EditText et_TweetText;
public static String consumerkey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
public static String consumersecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
public static String accesstoken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
public static String accesstokensecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
et_TweetText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_TweetText);

bt_tweetIt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_tweetIt);
bt_tweetIt.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
sTweet = et_TweetText.getText().toString();
Log.i(TAGTweet, "onClick- sTweet: " + sTweet);

if(CheckConnectivity()!=0){
Log.i(TAGTweet, "Internet Connection ON: ");
new UseTweeter().execute();
}
else {
Log.i(TAGTweet, "Internet Connection OFF: ");
ShowNoInternetConnectionAlert();
 }
}
 public class UseTweeter extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
 TweetThisMessage();
 return null;
  }
 }
public void TweetThisMessage(){
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setOAuthAccessToken(accesstoken);
builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accesstokensecret);
builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerkey);
builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumersecret);
OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(builder.build());
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(auth);
try {
Log.i(TAGTweet, "sTweet in TweetThisMessage(): " + sTweet);
twitter.updateStatus(sTweet);
} catch (TwitterException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return;
 }
}
```

Hope it helps.